# Oracle Apex authorised users access

Tags: database, oracle-apex, apex

I am looking to add an Authorization Option to my db project. I have added a 'manage users' page where you have the ability to add/edit/delete users who have access to view special data, however everyone is able to access this page as it stands.

I have created the USERS table with USER_TYPE as a flag for admin rights.

What I am looking to do is figure out how to recognize which user logs in (how to compare :APP_USER and check if it's DB user, if it is, then show the 'Manage Users' button)

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What have you tried ? Here are some stack overflow answers that can guide you in the right direction [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76855671/oracle-apex-application-access-control-authorization-and-authentication-mode), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553973/oracle-apex-restrict-report-data-based-on-authorization-schemes-and-roles), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71005493/oracle-apex-user-rights-and-previleges)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I went through and accepted the appropriate answers.

Comment: Have a look at those links to the other answers I posted in that 2nd comment. Maybe you can already get your question answered by them, if not pls be more clear about where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: Essentially I am looking for a button which will appear when a user from table USERS has logged in with appropriate USER_TYPE (this can be ADMIN or OTHER)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an authorization type "Admin" with scheme type "Exists SQL Query" and source

```
SELECT 1 
  FROM users 
 WHERE user_name = :APP_USER and 
       user_type = 'ADMIN'
```

(Change the columns to whatever they're called in your implementation)

Note that "Evaluation Point: Once per session" is probably fine but it might be annoying when developing because the changes are not re-evaluated. So when developing put it to "Once per page view"

Comment: Setting the Item = value to 1 on the button worked thanks Koen. Users can still change the page number in the URL to access the page. Do you know if I can use the same idea to block the page itself to 'OTHER' type ?

Comment: An authorization scheme can be set on any component, including a page. Just set the auth scheme on that page and you should be good